# Python SymPy factoring polynomial over complex numbers

Tags: python, sympy

I am using [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/) to factor polynomials over the complex numbers.

```
import sympy as sp

x, y = sp.symbols('x y')
z = sp.expand( (x - 1) * (y - 1) )

factorization_1 = sp.factor(z)
factorization_2 = sp.factor(z, extension = [sp.I])
```

Here, `z` has contains the expression `xy - x - y + 1`, and `factorization_1` indeed has the expected value `(x - 1)(y - 1)`, but for some reason `factorization_2` has the value `x - 1`.

Where did the factor `(y - 1)` go?

Comment: The problem seems to be that `factor(..., extension=...)` is only meant for [*univariate polynomials*](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/wester.html#univariate-factoring-over-gaussian-numbers).

Comment: I've reported this as a bug https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18895